# Quill Bold format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, text, quill

By default Quill use  tag to make text bold.
How replace Quill  tag with  which has inline style 'font-weight: 700'.

My workaround is here. But it is does not work when we use IPhone text formatting.

```
    class CustomBold extends Inline {
        static blotName = 'bold';
        static tagName = 'SPAN';
        static create(value: string) {
            const node = super.create(value) as HTMLSpanElement;
            node.style.fontWeight = '700';
            return node;
        }
        static formats(domNode: HTMLSpanElement) {
            return domNode.style.fontWeight === '700' ? true : false;
        }

        format(name: string, value: boolean) {
            if (name === 'bold') {
                this.domNode.style.fontWeight = value ? '700' : '400';
            } else {
                super.format(name, value);
            }
        }
        formats() {
            let formats = super.formats();
            formats['bold'] = CustomBold.formats(this.domNode);
            return formats;
        }
    }
```